# .htaccess template

Tags: .htaccess

I have an .htaccess template I have been working on that I want to submit for code review. I want to accomplish these things:

1. Custom error handling
2. Remove index.php if in url
3. Force HTTPS
4. Remove www.
5. SEO friendly URLs for a blog
6. Disable directory browsing
7. Protect .htaccess
8. Protect phpinfo.php

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on

ErrorDocument 504 /error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /error.php
ErrorDocument 501 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 408 /error.php
ErrorDocument 405 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule blog/([0-9]+)/ blog.php?id=$1

Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "^\.htaccess">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<Files phpinfo.php>
    AuthName "restricted" 
    AuthUserFile /home/ts/public_html/.htpasswd 
    AuthType Basic
    require valid-user
</Files>
```

Is there anything I am missing? Is there anything I should clean up? Is there a better way to do something that I've missed?

Comment: Which version of Apache?